# Ajax call not working with dynamic datatables created by jstl

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

Datatable 1.10.9 not making ajax call while using dynamic columns and data by jstl for each loop . getting ajax  Json error. 
        my code is : top line of jsp

output getting :not getting data in table it shows only column names but nothing in return of ajax response

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
         <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                <fmt:setLocale value="en" scope="session" />
                <fmt:setBundle basename="ApplicationResources" scope="session" />

        some other datatable refrences here .....
    <script language="JavaScript">  
        $(document).ready( function () {        
             var table;
             table= $('#example).DataTable( {
                        "processing": true,                                
                         dom: 'BRlfrtip',              

                         "ajax": {
                                   "url": "/example.so",

                                    "type": "GET"
                                     },
        "columns": [

                   <c:forEach items="${TableFields}" var="field"> 
                                            {"title":"<fmt:message key="label.${field.key}" />", "data":"${field.key}", "name":"${field.key}" },
            ]                               </c:forEach> 
           } );

        </script>


    html  code : 

    </head>
    <body>
    <fmt:setLocale value="en" scope="session" />
            <fmt:setBundle basename="ApplicationResources" scope="session" />
        <h2><font color="#4B0082">List All Data</font></h2>

            <div id="gridContainer">
                <div id="gridContent" class="blockContent">
             <div style="width: auto; height: 750px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
                    <table id="example" class="display " cellspacing="0" width="100%"  >
                        <thead></thead>                     
                    <tfoot>
                        </tfoot>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
    </body>
    </html>

         using spring mvc ,controller has list method .
```

Comment: Um, you got that JS inside some <script> tags? Please show us the whole code chunk, and please include the response from the AJAX call, or the exact console error you're seeing.

Comment: yes i updated the question , m getting nothing in ajax response and getting nullpointer exception from controller side.  it was working before perfctly when i was not using jstl

Comment: this loop is giving me same thing which i  hardcoded before i.e {title:  data:}

Comment: Is the ajax call even being made? Check your Dev Tools to see if the network request is being made.

Comment: IN Network, have something under request header but nothing under request body

Comment: Ok, can you please show the OUTPUT of your forEach loop? You should see it in the SOURCE of the page, or using Dev Tools, if you inspect the HTML. Paste that for us.

Comment: yes i have near about 50 columns so i m writing here for one column output which loop gives me on page source         "columns": [ {"tiltle": customer name,  "data":customername}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94122/discussion-between-josh-kg-and-saren).